# How does a 'Highly Swept leading-edge' delta wing reduces fuel burn and increases range?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, supersonic

[Spike Aerospace](http://www.spikeaerospace.com/s-512-supersonic-jet/)  claims to have designed an aircraft called S-512, with maximum speed of 1.8 mach and cruise speed of 1.6 mach, speaking about the notable changes in the aircraft, Spike Aerospace [says](http://www.foxnews.com/travel/2015/07/08/spike-aerospaces-s-512-supersonic-jet-promises-to-fly-from-new-york-to-london/?cmpid=cmty_twitter_fn):

> “The new delta wing of the S-512 delivers high aerodynamic efficiency and improved flight performance in both low-speed flight and supersonic cruise,” “The **highly swept leading-edge** reduces wave drag and consequently reduces fuel burn and increases range.

How does a *highly swept leading-edge* helps?

Comment: Spike aerospace has not built anything, they have a concept.

Comment: Concorde was not a faliure because of technology. It failed because of loss of consumer trust after the 2000 accident (which was some other airplane's fault) and decreasing passengers after 9/11

Comment: Spike Aerospace have [1-10 employees](https://www.linkedin.com/company/spike-aerospace), operate out of office suite 304 at 349 Newbury St, Boston and, so far as I can tell, have no manufacturing facilities or history. I don't think there's any way to be *sure* Spike will ever build even one S-512, let alone support them in commercial operation for over a quarter of a century.

Comment: While they have just a concept, @RedGrittyBrick, I'm glad they have that. If Orville and Wilbur hadn't dreamed despite their father's protests, we might still be driving NYC to LA...

Comment: @VictorJuliet: These are not the only reasons for ending Concorde commercial adventure. Concorde was not able to continue due to the pollution, noise, and once revolutionary but now old technical design, which was a factor in the 2000 accident, not mentioning the ticket price (the customers were able to afford it and happy to pay anyway). 9/11 did not slow down air traffic, which is increasing.